# defining a page id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway of defining a pageID sort of thing to an html page, for using in javascript code...

Comment: What are you trying to acheive ? This is really vague ...

Comment: what some calls vague at a times become new theories after some time... And also what you call vague may be some creativity of someone...

Comment: Vague and abstract are not the same thing. Abstract things may become new theories and be creativity. Vague things are the result of the inability of an author to articulate him/herself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify an id on the body?

`<body id='some_unique_id_for_page'>`

Comment: ok fine, thanks. Now to take use of this id can we anyhow fetch through javascript whats the id of this tag ?

Comment: Yes, easily. In jQuery, it would simple be `$('body').attr('id')`. In native javascript, it would be something like: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id`.

Answer (score 1):

An identifier for the whole page? Why not use the URL?